# Obtener la cantidad mas grande y su id en sql

Tags: sql

Tengo tres registros y quiero afectar al de mayor cantidad lo obtengo con el MAX(Cantidad). para hacerle una resta a la cantidad mayor. pero se afecta a los tres registros que tengo. Ocupo ademar de traerme la ultima cantidad también obtener su id para afectar solo ese registro?

Saludos

---

[image]

Esta es mi consulta para obtener el id OrdenEntradaDetID=1 para actualizar la cantidad mas grande que en este caso es la 1166.66 de la OrdenEntradaDetID 1.

Comment: Necesitamos más información. Qué motor de base de datos estás usando?, cuál es tu consulta actual?, tienes un ejemplo de datos y el resultado que quieres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la id del registro con mayor cantidad seria asi:

```
DECLARE @Id_Mayor_Cantidad int

SELECT @Id_Mayor_Cantidad = (SELECT LlavePrimaria FROM Tabla WHERE Cantidad=(SELECT MAX(Cantidad) FROM Tabla))
```

Y ya tendrías la Id en la variable @Id_Mayor_Cantidad

Comment: Gracias Alexander

Comment: De nada :) Si te funciono recuerda puntuar la respuesta como correcta para que futuros usuarios que se encuentren con esta pregunta sepan que esta respuesta resolvió la pregunta